# Flutter not updating firebase collection

Tags: firebase, flutter

I can't seem to get my flutter app to update my firebase collection when I get a user to sign up. I get no error messages or any warnings, only thing I can think of is if something is null and therefore not updating but I can't see how since my authentication works and I can see the user in firebase authentication tab.

I've checked my rules and it looks okay:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
///sign up function
  Future<String?> signUp(
      {required String email, required String password}) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);

      var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE').doc().update({
        'email': currentUser!.email,
        'firstName': 'Joe',
        'lastName': 'bloggs',
        'userID': currentUser.uid,
      });

      return "Signed up";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
```

my database looks as follows:

[image]

Main.dart code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationService>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationService>().authStateChanges,
          initialData: null,
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        ),
        home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();

    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      print('User is NOT signed in!');
      return const WelcomeScreen();
    }
    print('User is signed in!');
    return const MainScreen();

  }
}
```

Comment: did you init firebase App?

Comment: @THEODORE not sure what you mean?

Comment: and did you add the google service config for android or ios?

Comment: added google services for both iOS and android, authentication works fine its just pushing the data to the table

Comment: Firebase.initializeApp(),

Comment: Yeah its initialised in main, I've added it to my main question

Comment: just edit .doc().update to .doc(currentUser.uid).update or use .doc().add.  did it work?

Comment: add method threw and exception as not being defined. the .doc(currentUser.uid) didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE').doc().update({
  'email': currentUser!.email,
  'firstName': 'Joe',
  'lastName': 'bloggs',
  'userID': currentUser.uid,
});
```

From the reference docs for [`doc()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html):

> If no path is provided, an auto-generated ID is used.

So your `doc()` call (without an ID) generates a new unique ID, and return a `DocumentReference` to that new, non-existing document. The problem after that though is that `update()` can only update existing documents, it never creates a document.

---

Since it seems that you don't know whether a document for the user exists, you should:

1. Pass the UID in `doc()` as @THEODORE answered

   ```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE')
       .doc(currentUser.uid)
   ```
2. Call `set` instead of update.

   ```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE')
       .doc(currentUser.uid)
       .set({...})
   ```

   If the document may already exist, and you want to merge the new values with any existing values, you can [pass `SetOptions` to `set`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/set.html) for that.

   ```
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE')
       .doc(currentUser.uid)
       .set({...}, SetOptions(merge : true))
   ```

Comment: Thanks appreciate that! Good description of the .doc() missed that line about auto generating, which explains it. I also found I needed to and an await before it too. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks For explaining it more for us.

Answer (score 3):

I see the issue "update method needs an ID" only "add method doesn’t "

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE').doc(currentUser.uid).update({
    'email': currentUser!.email,
    'firstName': 'Joe',
    'lastName': 'bloggs',
    'userID': currentUser.uid,
  });
```

or

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE').add({
    'email': currentUser!.email,
    'firstName': 'Joe',
    'lastName': 'bloggs',
    'userID': currentUser.uid,
  });
```

Comment: just edit  .doc().update to .doc(currentUser.uid).update

Comment: None of those methods seemed to work unfortunately :(

Comment: sorry   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USER_TABLE').add({
    'email': currentUser!.email,
    'firstName': 'Joe',
    'lastName': 'bloggs',
    'userID': currentUser.uid,
  });

remove the doc()

Comment: add 'await'  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection ...

Comment: the await was what was missing! cheers for the help appreciate it. Do you want to put that in an answer and ill mark it as the solution?

Comment: From the reference docs for [`doc()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/CollectionReference/doc.html): "If no path is provided, an auto-generated ID is used." So you can call `doc()` without an ID, and it will generate a new unique ID, and return a `DocumentReference` to that new document. The problem after that though is that `update()` can only update existing documents, it never creates a document. --- So while you're correct that OP needs to pass the UID to `doc()`, calling `doc()` without arguments is valid (otherwise the SDK would raise an error)